# How to install Ubuntu server on a Dell R210 with S100 raid controller

Tags: ubuntu, dell, software-raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server on a R210 with a S100 raid controller.
It's a software controlled RAID, and it's not recognized in Ubuntu. So I guess I have to disable it and use the software raid provided in Ubuntu (mbabm).

I'm a bit lost about the process. In the BIOS, I can select RAID or AHCI. I don't know which one to choose.
Then in the booting, I can press CTRL+R to access the RAID options. Should I use the nonRaid option again there ?

It seems that the appropriate driver (mtp2sas) is not present on the server version. So I have downloaded the desktop version, on which I'll add the ubuntu-server package.
Am I right there ? Should I follow this procedure to configure the raid ? (https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/advanced-installation.html)

Thank for your guidance !

Comment: As Hubert said, I disabled the Raid option and created a software RAID during the installation. After first restart, I get an error message, saying mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/[...] on /root failed.

Comment: The bug is explained here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/partman-base/+bug/569900 - to fix it, partitions have to be installed manually, with some space left on each disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RAID/AHCI setting is for the controller integrated in the mainboard, not the add-on card.

And yes, you need to disable all RAID settings in the add-on card, this way it *should* be seen as a simple SATA controller which are supported in linux. The howto you provided should guide you through the configuration.

Comment: So the first setting (RAID/AHCI) has no influence whatsoever on my configuration ?

Comment: Yes, in fact, most mainboards from linux perspective don't behave differently with RAID and AHCI setting. Though it's better to leave this setting at AHCI, just to be safe.